# canceling print operating crashes Swift Mac desktop app

Tags: swift, macos, printing

I have had a problem with printing a certificate with a background image and overlay text.

My solution after much research is to convert a view to an image and print that and it works UNLESS the print dialogue is canceled then get a crash.

I have tried many versions of the code, even a test app that only does the print function and always get the crash on canceling print. If the certificate is printed no apparent issues.

following in one of many versions of the code I have tried, all with the same result on cancel.

App is Mac desktop, SwiftUi latest everything.

```
         let contentView = ContentView()
     let contentRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 620, height: 860)

     let newWindow = NSWindow(
         contentRect: contentRect,
         styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
         backing: .buffered, defer: false)

     newWindow.contentView = NSHostingView(rootView: contentView)

     let myNSBitMapRep = newWindow.contentView!.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: contentRect)!

     newWindow.contentView!.cacheDisplay(in: contentRect, to: myNSBitMapRep)


     let myNSImage = NSImage(size: myNSBitMapRep.size)
     myNSImage.addRepresentation(myNSBitMapRep)
    
    
    var printView = NSImageView(frame: NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 620, height: 860))
    printView.image = myNSImage
    
    let printInfo = NSPrintInfo()
    printInfo.horizontalPagination = .fit
    printInfo.verticalPagination = .automatic
    printInfo.leftMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.rightMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.topMargin = 0.0
    printInfo.bottomMargin = 0.0
    
    let paperBounds = printInfo.imageablePageBounds
    let origin = paperBounds.origin
    let size = paperBounds.size
    print( "Origin X:\(origin.x), y:\(origin.y) - Size width:\(size.width), height:\(size.height)")
    
    let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo)
    printOperation.showsPrintPanel = true
    printOperation.showsProgressPanel = true
    printOperation.canSpawnSeparateThread = true
    printOperation.run()
```

Comment: What happens if you comment out the three lines with a bool value before printOperation.run()?

Comment: I would try commenting out all lines between let printInfo = NSPrintInfo() and let printOperation = NSPrintOperation(view: printView, printInfo: printInfo) .

Comment: Is there a crash message in console when this happens?

Comment: @ElTomato Some times I just hate development!
Just rerun the app to get the error message text and NO ERROR!
The worst possible result, can't fix it till it comes back hopefully not just after the release!

Comment: That's all right.  It kind of rings me a bell if you say the application crashes when you cancel the printing job.  I haven't seen it for 3 to 4 years, at least.