# How to print a SwiftUI View with text and images on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui, printing

I'm trying to print the contents of a SwiftUI view on macOS.  According to the documentation, this seems like it should be possible by giving the `NSPrintOperation` an `NSView` created by an `NSHostingView`.  The SwiftUI view's body contains several Text views and an Image view, with borders around those views.  All of the Text gets printed, however the Image and the borders are not visible. Is there something else needed to make this work?

Here is a sample to demonstrate the problem.  Just create a new macOS App, replace the ContentView with the code below and then enable Printing in Signing & Capabilities:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Print", action: self.onPrint )
            Divider()
            Print_Preview()
        }
    }
    
    private func onPrint() {
        let pi = NSPrintInfo.shared
        pi.topMargin = 0.0
        pi.bottomMargin = 0.0
        pi.leftMargin = 0.0
        pi.rightMargin = 0.0
        pi.orientation = .landscape
        pi.isHorizontallyCentered = false
        pi.isVerticallyCentered = false
        pi.scalingFactor = 1.0
                
        let rootView = Print_Preview()
        let view = NSHostingView(rootView: rootView)
        view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
        let po = NSPrintOperation(view: view, printInfo: pi)
        po.printInfo.orientation = .landscape
        po.showsPrintPanel = true
        po.showsProgressPanel = true
        
        po.printPanel.options.insert(NSPrintPanel.Options.showsPaperSize)
        po.printPanel.options.insert(NSPrintPanel.Options.showsOrientation)
        
        if po.run() {
            print("In Print completion")
        }
    }
    
    struct Print_Preview: View {
        var body: some View {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text("Bordered Text Above Bordered Image")
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
                    .padding(5)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
                Image(systemName: "printer")
                    .resizable()
                    .padding(5)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                Text("Bordered Text Below Bordered Image")
                    .font(.system(size: 8))
                    .padding(5)
                    .border(Color.black, width: 2)
            }
            .padding()
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .background(Color.white)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        }
    }

}
```

Also, here are screenshots of the App and Print Panel.

[image: Sample App screenshot]

[image: Print Panel screenshot]

Comment: Maybe this helps: [canceling print operating crashes Swift Mac desktop app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62593232/canceling-print-operating-crashes-swift-mac-desktop-app)

Comment: @Willeke, thanks for the pointer!  I was able to adapt that code and confirm that it works.

Comment: Is the original code working as expected on macOS 14 or 13.5?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @Willeke for the comment with a pointer and to @user2120275 for asking a different question that happened to contain the trick needed to fix my problem.  The solution is to create an `NSImageView` from the `NSView` returned by the `NSHostingView`, and then print that `NSImageView` instead of the original `NSView`.

My sample code above can be made to work by replacing these two lines:

```
view.frame.size = CGSize(width: 300, height: 300)
let po = NSPrintOperation(view: view, printInfo: pi)
```

with the following:

```
let contentRect = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
view.frame.size = contentRect.size

let newWindow = NSWindow(
    contentRect: contentRect,
    styleMask: [.titled, .closable, .miniaturizable, .resizable, .fullSizeContentView],
    backing: .buffered, defer: false)
newWindow.contentView = view

let myNSBitMapRep = newWindow.contentView!.bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplay(in: contentRect)!
newWindow.contentView!.cacheDisplay(in: contentRect, to: myNSBitMapRep)

let myNSImage = NSImage(size: myNSBitMapRep.size)
myNSImage.addRepresentation(myNSBitMapRep)

let nsImageView = NSImageView(frame: contentRect)
nsImageView.image = myNSImage

let po = NSPrintOperation(view: nsImageView, printInfo: pi)
```